# Using ErrorController without raising exceptions

Tags: grails

I see the Grails pattern, where you can configure your UrlMappings so that certain types of exceptions are handling in a specific Controller which returns specific responses to your client.

Very good.

However, is there anyway to invoke the functionality of your ErrorController without raising an exception?

For example, a user enters the wrong password - you don't want to throw an exception because it is not really an exception.  Instead, you want a service to return an InvalidResponse to a Controller and you would love then for the Controller to delegate out to your ErrorController where you have your generic, error handling.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: You can always inspect the result from your service call and determine if it's valid/invalid and use foward(controller: 'myErrorController', action: 'theActionToBeCalled'). "Valid" vs "Invalid" without the use of exceptions is up to you to determine and implement.

Comment: Are you using Spring Security Core? If you are, you should be able to specify the action that happens on auth failure specifically. In a more general sense, a simple redirect should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of [redirect](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html), [forward](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/forward.html) or [chain](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html) to determine what to do in every case you have